# What does git merge origin branchname do?

Tags: git, git-merge

Note the lack of a "/" in the command.

I am a git novice.

I am working on the same codebase, same branch, on two separate machines (one dev machine, one test machine). I pushed code on dev-machine.

```
git push origin branchname
```

On test-machine, I did:

```
git fetch origin 
git merge origin branchname
```

Git reported "Already up-to-date. Yeeah!" But I knew I wasn't.

Eventually I did the correct

```
git merge origin/branchname
```

What happened when I screwed up and did:

```
git merge origin branchname
```

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge mentions an "octopus merge" but "origin" is special (not a branch name) so I don't think that happened.

Comment: Yup. Duplicate. I voted to close my question. Should I delete it instead?

Comment: You won't be able to delete your question now that answers to it have been posted. Anyway, duplicates are not all bad; they help people (who may not all use the same search query) converge to a solution to their problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means "merge the branches `origin` and `branchname` into the current branch" -- effectively requesting that two other branches be merged into your current branch.  Note that `origin` is a remote; when used as a commit identifier, it is equivalent to `origin/HEAD` (which typically points to `origin/master`).

So, assuming that you had `branchname` checked out already, you were attempting to merge the branch with itself, and this is a no-op.  It sounds like `origin/HEAD` was already "merged" (the commit is an ancestor of `branchname`) so that also was also resolved as a no-op.

In other words, both commits you tried to merge into your branch were already part of your branch history, so Git correctly didn't do anything.

Comment: Using the term "[three-way merge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(revision_control)#Three-way_merge)" in this context has the potential to confuse. You should instead write "the merge of two branches into another" or something like that.

Comment: @Jubobs Fair point, sometimes I forget that three-way merge generally refers to how files are merged.  It's not an inaccurate term in this context but could be misleading based on how the term is usually used, and I understand that.

Comment: One oddity that may be worth mentioning in your answer is that the default commit message suggested by Git after `git merge origin` is `Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin'`, which is misleading.

Answer (score -2):

When you have branchname on a remote origin, then on your local you call origin/brachname, that is you make a local copy of branch on the remote. origin/brachname is a branch.

So what you did was fetch the branch (branchname) from the remote (origin). Now you have a local copy (origin/branchname) which you then merge into your local branch (branchname).

Comment: This appears to restate information the OP already knows, but does not address the particular form of Git command (`git merge origin branchname`) that OP does not understand.  As such, it does not actually answer the question at all.